# VB.NET Is there a way to create a pre-processor constant that behaves as a simple text substitution?

Tags: vb.net, preprocessor, constants, substitution

VB.NET 2010, .NET 4

Hello,

I would like to do (something like) the following:

```
\#Const T = "Byte()"

Public Class MyClass
  Inherits SomeGenericClass(Of T)

  .. other code ..
End Class
```

And have it act the same as if I'd typed

```
Public Class MyClass
  Inherits SomeGenericClass(Of Byte())

  .. other code ..
End Class
```

It's not so much that i *have* to do it this way, I'm just curious if such a thing is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Brian

Comment: How did a C programmer end up writing VB.NET code?  Of course this doesn't work.  It never will.  Ever.

Comment: Okay, I can accept that.  Is it possible to elaborate on why?  I just want to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.  The Visual Basic and C# designers decided not to allow a C-like preprocessor, because they felt it led to a lot of errors and confusion.  It is very easy to write C macros that behave in unintended ways, and the VB and C# designers felt that safety for a broad range of developers took priority.  Therefore defines in VB and C# are only 'defined' or 'undefined' rather than having values.

[Eric Gunnerson discusses this from a C# perspective here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/09/why-doesn-t-c-support-define-macros.aspx), and I think the design reasoning for VB.NET was essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

You only have: [`#Const #If #Else #Endif`](http://www.bigresource.com/VB-VB-Preprocessor-directives--MhjSVmmGlV.html)
But, you can use another program to generate the code.